# Two different ways to calculate the probability for a negative value - are they equivalent?

Tags: normal-distribution

I want to calculate

$$
P(Z\leq-1.8)
$$

My math book teaches this one:

$$
F_Z(0) - F_1(1.8) = 0.5 - F_1(1.8)
$$

This makes sense.

But what about the following? Does it also make sense, is it equivalent?

$$
F_Z(1.8) - F_2(1.8)
$$

I am asking, because the results are not exactly the same. According to my lookup table, the values are as follows:

$$
F_Z(1.8)=0.9641\\
F_1(1.8)=0.4641\\
F_2(1.8)=0.9281
$$

Given these numbers, the result of the math book is $0.5 - 0.4641=0.0359$ and my result is $0.036$.

---

Explanation for $F_Z$, $F_1$ and $F_2$ according to my Math book:

$$
F_Z : P(Z\leq z)\\
F_1 : P(0\leq Z\leq z)\\
F_2 : P(-z\leq Z\leq z)
$$

Comment: What are $F_1$ and $F_2$?

Comment: @5xum I updated my question with the definitions. HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
 F_Z(z) & =P(Z\le z) \\
& = P((Z \le -z) or (-z \lt Z \le z))\\
& = P(Z \le -z) + P(-z \lt Z \le z)\\
& = F_Z(-z) + F_2(z)
\end{align}$$

Hence

$F_Z(-z) =F_Z(z) - F_2(z)$

Your text book is relying on the symmetry of the standard normal distribution about zero so that
$$ \begin{align}\\F_Z(-z) & = P(Z \le -z)\\ 
& = P(Z \ge z) \tag{by symmetry}\\
& =  1 - P(Z \le z)\\
& = 1 - [P((Z \le 0) or (0 \lt Z \le z))]\\
& = 1 - [P(Z \le 0) + P(0 \lt Z \le z)]\\
& = [1 - P(Z \le 0)] - P(0 \lt Z \le z)\\
& = P(Z \le 0) - P(0 \lt Z \le z) \tag{since P(Z $\le$ 0) = 0.5}\\
& = F_Z(0) - F_1(z)
\end{align}$$

So, yes the two are equivalent and the slight numerical difference you have got when calculating $F_Z(-1.8)$ these two different ways is because the lookup numbers are not exact values but are accurate only to 4 places of decimals.

Comment: Thanks :-) A third way would be $1 - F_Z(1.8)$, right?

Comment: Yes. Sketching the normal curve and drawing out the areas under the curve represented by the various $F$ functions is a good and intuitive way of understanding the relationships between them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's how I got to those different solutions in the first place, but I was a bit unsure because of the $\leq$...